# Symbols for Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, visual-studio-debugging, pdb-files

The images below show the module window which shows all PDB files loading properly, but when hovering over my breakpoints I still see the second image, saying symbols have not been loaded. How do I get my breakpoints to work??

[Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSwVO.png)

[image: Error]

Comment: Click "Modules" for the module window, not sure why it shows one image and not the other.

Comment: The VS2005 was really old version, actually Microsoft didn't support VS2005 now since we also have no that Environment, if possible, you could refer to my suggestion, share us the latest information, but if possible, I suggest you use the higher VS versions which would have much more features:)

Comment: I am not looking for MS support, I understand it is old but this is a constraint I am forced to deal with and cannot upgrade to a higher VS version.

Comment: @ mgrenier, So it still has this issue with my answer, am I right? If so, do you debug your app in debug mode(not release mode)? Please disable the Optimize for your project, of course, you could also load the symbols manually: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

(1)Try to change the target CPU (X86/X64/Any CPU)in your project property, and rebuild it again.

(2)Please also make sure that it is not related to the .NET version. Make sure that your project was in debug mode, not in release mode.

(3)In your project property->Compile: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07bysfz2(v=vs.80).aspx, Generate debug info=Full.

(4)Enable the Symbols Server Under Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols.

(5)Tools->option->Debugging->General-> disable 'Requires source files to exactly match the original version. Debug your app again.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Debug/Options/Debugging/General and check 'Enable Just My Code'

Comment: I have tried both with this checked an unchecked...still says "no symbols have been loaded"

Comment: Did you rebuild the solution after checking it?

Comment: I don't think if this helps but when I check that in the module window it says "skipped loading" instead of loaded...but in both cases when hovering over the over the break point it says not loaded.